# Find out if the price was zero when looking through php array of price history/changes

Tags: php

I have all the price changes in a array like this (date, pricechange). It is always in date order:

```
$pricehistory = array (
    '2013-11-04' => 10,
    '2013-11-10' => 0,
    '2013-12-01' => 10
);
```

What I need is to find out if the price for a specific date was zero.

```
function was_free($date) {
    // return boolean
}

was_free('2013-11-11'); //should return true;

was_free('2013-12-01'); //should return false;
```

Can someone please help me figuring out how to do this? I think I need to loop through the $pricehistory array backwards, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Is `was_free('2013-11-11'); //should return true;` a typo, or do you actually want that date to return true? Since it's not in the array.

Comment: I think there's something you're not explaining clearly if you think you need to scan the array rather than just access the specific element directly.

Comment: 2003-11-11 should return true since the price was changed to zero 2013-11-10 and was zero until 2013-12-01.

Comment: What he probably means is that the array resembles the price history of 1 product, and the keys only reflect whenever the price was changed of that single product. In other words, the dates after a given key (but which aren't in the array because there wasn't a price change), and before the next key (as the price changed), have the same value as the given key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//$default - returned if price is not exits 
function was_free($price_history, $current_date, $default = FALSE) {

    if(isset($price_history[$current_date]))
    {
        return empty($price_history[$current_date]);
    }

    $current_timestamp = strtotime($current_date);

    $history_timestamp = array();

    foreach ($price_history as $date => $price)
    {
        $history_timestamp[strtotime($date)] = $price;
    }

    $history_timestamp[$current_timestamp] = NULL;

    ksort($history_timestamp);

    $previous_price = ($default) ? FALSE : TRUE;

    foreach ($history_timestamp as $timestamp => $price)
    {   
        if($timestamp == $current_timestamp)
        {           
            break;
        }

        $previous_price = $price;
    }

    return empty($previous_price);
}


$price_history = array (
    '2013-11-04' => 10,
    '2013-11-10' => 0,
    '2013-12-01' => 10
);

// run !!
var_dump(was_free($price_history, '2013-11-03'));
var_dump(was_free($price_history, '2013-11-04'));
var_dump(was_free($price_history, '2013-11-09'));
var_dump(was_free($price_history, '2013-11-10'));
var_dump(was_free($price_history, '2013-11-11'));
var_dump(was_free($price_history, '2013-12-01'));
var_dump(was_free($price_history, '2013-12-02'));
```

Comment: Thank you. But maby I didn't explain my problem in detail. 2013-11-11 should return true since the price was changed to zero 2013-11-10 and didn't change again until 2013-12-01

Comment: I think it'll help you

Comment: Thank you. I've tried it but this returns false. Should return true.

     var_dump(was_free($price_history, '2013-11-10'));

Comment: sorry, function is fixed.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful! It's almost working now. I've tried it but it seems to return true on all dates that price is unknown (before 2013-11-04). Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: Added param $default - it is returned if price is not exits.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function was_free($date) {
    return array_key_exists($date,$pricehistory) && $pricehistory[$date] === 0;
}
```

Since the $pricehistory isn't in the scope of the function, you may pass it as a parameter or access it using global.

Comment: Thank you. But maby I didn't explain my problem in detail. 2013-11-11 should return true since the price was changed to zero 2013-11-10 and didn't change again until 2013-12-01.